# Busy sharing cars

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, distributions

Given a pool of C cars available to use by P people and that the average person uses a car t percent of the time, how often will there be zero cars available for use?

For example, if there are 500 people and 50 cars, and the average percent of time a person uses a car is 10%, how likely will there be zero cars available for use by the remaining 450 people?

Comment: I think that using Erlang's work on traffic for phone calls would be a very appropriate method.  There is some probability of a call being made (or car used), and the time it is used by an individual is probably relatively exponential in distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the use of a car by one person is independent from any other person using or not using a car.

Then, $Pr(\text{use a car}) = t$.

Therefore, $Pr(\text{all cars taken}) = {P \choose C}t^C(1-t)^{P-C}$.

Why? Let's say that $P=500$ and $C=50$ and $t=0.1$, as you said. Then for one possible selection of 50 people to occupy all the available cars, the chance that this will happen is the probability that 50 will be in a car ($t^C$) *and* the other 450 won't ($(1-t)^{P-C}$).

But there is more than one possible combination of drivers and non-drivers. That's where the combination number ${P \choose C}$ comes in: it tells you the number of all possible combinations of selecting $C$ elements from $P$ elements without repetition and when order doesn't matter.

So for your example, $Pr() = {500 \choose 50}0.1^{50} 0.9^{450} \approx 0.0594 \approx 6\%$.

Comment: The independence assumption is not plausible for this problem.

Comment: No, but the assumption that it is a homework problem is.